# Using oauth2 for my own mobile client?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0

I understand that oauth2 is used to allow a third-party access to resources on bahalf of a user.

I am looking for best practices or suggestions for the following case:

- We are building a social network with its own mobile client app.
- Currently, we will only allow our own app access to resources.

That means, an oauth2 implementation might be too heavy, because the user is using our own client.

But when looking at this in an abstract way, we could use oauth2, and have the user allow our own app access. In other words: the Resource Owner (user) would allow the Resource Server (our own server) to serve data to the Client (in this case our own app which the user used for authorization).

Given the fact that we may want to give tokens to "real" third-parties at a later point, would you implement oauth2 right away or would you suggest anything else (and not use oauth2)?

Thanks for your insight and opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Well...it is a tradeoff: building something that just delivers what you need today and prepare for a future.

I would advise against building all that identity infrastructure from scratch. There're a few options that you might be able to use, depending on the platform you are working on. [Authorization Server](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.AuthorizationServer) is one. It is open source (on .NET). There are also other commercial offerings.

Comment: Thanks @EugenioPace - do you know of anything Java-based that is well known and open source? Anybody else who has already used a specific server implementation and would or would not recommend it? Thanks for your feedback.